# Doing cmu15-445 recently,in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: format, clang

To meet the formatting requirements, I ran "make format" in the command line and got the following output.

[image]

can someone help me with the

```
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: ' CLANG_FORMAT_BIN-NOTFOUND'
```

Comment: I removed the build, and run "make format" again got the "Built target format "   However after I run "make check-clang-tidy" I got "Unable to run clang-tidy" as a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Check `CMakeLists.txt` and make sure `clang-format` and `clang-tidy` have correct version(8 or 12).

```
# clang-format
find_program(CLANG_FORMAT_BIN
        NAMES clang-format clang-format-12
        HINTS ${BUSTUB_CLANG_SEARCH_PATH})
if ("${CLANG_FORMAT_BIN}" STREQUAL "CLANG_FORMAT_BIN-NOTFOUND")
    message(WARNING "BusTub/main couldn't find clang-format.")
else()
    message(STATUS "BusTub/main found clang-format at ${CLANG_FORMAT_BIN}")
endif()

# clang-tidy
find_program(CLANG_TIDY_BIN
        NAMES clang-tidy clang-tidy-12
        HINTS ${BUSTUB_CLANG_SEARCH_PATH})
if ("${CLANG_TIDY_BIN}" STREQUAL "CLANG_TIDY_BIN-NOTFOUND")
    message(WARNING "BusTub/main couldn't find clang-tidy.")
else()
    # Output compile_commands.json
    set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)
    message(STATUS "BusTub/main found clang-tidy at ${CLANG_TIDY_BIN}")
endif()
```